# Adding CefSharp via NuGet causes all reference to be lost

Tags: vb.net, nuget, cefsharp

I'm trying to add CefSharp.WinForms (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) to my solution via NuGet. However, after adding it all of my existing reference (including System, System.Core, etc) are lost.

[image: warnings]

If I remove the CefSharp packages and then clean/rebuild, the references are all found again.

Any idea(s) why this is happening and how I can fix?

Side note, I followed the guidelines for adding AnyCPU support and the error still didn't resolve. Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Start with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/73/NuGet/Readme.txt#L12

Comment: A working example of `AnyCPU` support is at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/demo/anycpu It looks like you've missed a step with implementing `AnyCPU` support.

Comment: Thanks both, however I did follow the instructions first time... I wouldn't post here otherwise! Even if I changed to using x64 or x86 target architecture it doesn't like the references.

Comment: Are you changing the solution target or just the project target? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/73/NuGet/Readme.txt#L10

Comment: When trying AnyCPU did you edit your project file as specified? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/demo/anycpu/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.csproj#L31

Comment: I believe I did, yes, although it's possible I did it incorrectly.